# Sending from a certain port in c#

Tags: c#, tcp

I have written code that sends data using TCP on port 30175 on the client side server. The problem I am having is that even though I close the port between each string it is always sending from the same port on the server side causing the client to not recognize it as a new connection or new data. I would like to be able to specify the port i am sending from my server side. The program is written in c#.

Comment: It's not quite clear what your problem is here.  Are you trying to chaneg the client or the server?

Comment: Using TCP you should not care about what port data is sent from - the port number only has meaning while connecting.

Answer (score 0):

The server listening on port 30175 will send data from port 30175. If you want a different port number then you must open a new port on the server and get the client to connect to it.

My suggestion is that you fix the problem that the client is not recognizing the new connection and new data.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets address your issue.  You choose which port the server is using when you `Bind()` to the socket.  At this point, you have the option to specify a port. (If you don't then it chooses an available one for you.)

The question I have for you is... if you have your server switches ports all the time... Then how will the client know what port to `Connect()` to?

**A Different Approach**

Instead of closing the port between each `string` as you described before... consider setting up a protocol.  For example: Have the client connect, then send the length (`int`) of the `string` in ASCII.  Then send the ASCII `byte[]`.  After this, repeat the process. (So the server would be ready for another `int`.)

This way your code isn't spending as much time `binding/connecting` to sockets.

Comment: I worded this bad now that i am reading this. so let me clear this up. the process of the code is that it connects through a TCP port to the client. it then sends GPS data for a device and disconnects (without disconnecting it would not recognize the other devices on the client side). The problem i am having is that my client side is recognizing all of the data as one in the same because (even though they are 30 seconds apart) it is always reading it from the same TCP port. so what i would like to do is send the data from my server/code side from a port to which i assign during each loop.

Comment: I think I'm confused about what you mean when you say `server` vs `client`.  A `client` connects to a `server`. Not the other way around.  And I still think the approach to close a socket between each round of GPS data is bad.

Comment: Okay getting rid of server client scenario. I am sending GPS data from IP1 to IP2:30175. what i would like to do is establish that when i send the data from server 1 that it will always come from IP1:xxxxx.

Comment: On the client side (IP1)... you could first `Bind()` to a port and then `Connect()` to the server.  This would cause the client to have a different port each time while still connected... but I actually don't think the server will be able to tell which port the client is bound to... That information is stored in the actual TCP message... but I don't know how you would get that specific information.  (And I still don't like this approach... Just come up with a protocol!)